# Applications of information theory in economics?

Tags: economics, information-theory

What are some direct applications of [information theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) in economics theory and/or finance? Any relevant articles, surveys, or book references are appreciated (especially if they are targeted to readers unfamiliar with economics).

Answer (score 6):

An example in finance is represented by  credit risk modeling. In this specific application one tries to classify debtors with classification / prediction models. In other words, one is interested in knowing whether a given debtor-which is represented by a collection of features extracted from financial statements and qualitative information-will default or not, in a given horizon (usually 12 months). [Classification problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) are then solved using (among others) [KNN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) (K-nearest neighbors), regression / [classification trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree) and [logistic regressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).

More modern methods are represented by SVM ([support vector machines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine)) or [generalized mixed linear models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_mixed_model) (GLMM).
In statistical model selection and classification tree formation it is quite common to use "optimization / model selection" criteria coming from information theory.
The most known is probably the [AIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion) (Akaike's Information Criterium). These criteria are usually defined by formulae involving [Shannon's entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)), or [Kullback Leibler's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) divergence. This latter is the Bregman divergence generated by (minus) the Shannon entropy. More general formulations can also be used.

Comment: @MCH did it help?

Answer (score 1):

-Stochastic portfolio theory by Dr Robert Fernholz (2002) uses Shannon's entropy measure to create  functionally generated portfolios of stocks. Today, Dr Fernholz runs a Fund based on his insights into Stock Market dynamics.
-IN portfolio management Constant proportion insurance (CPPI)  is an algorithm of portfolio management that allows controlled behavior portfolios an a degree of capital protection. CPPI algorithm is derived from Kelly's Criterion for capital management which in turn is an application to gambling of Shannon's Information Theory.

Answer (score 0):

A recent paper was published using information theory to derive the Black-Scholes formula

https://www.mdpi.com/1911-8074/16/12/501